# How to get range of values between two numbers while supplying iteration number?

Tags: javascript, math

How can I get values from one number to second number with equally incrementing values, if I supply iteration number? Result should include both start and end values.

Here is example of hardcoded solution

```
var first = 1;
var second = 1.4;
var times = 5;
var result = [1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4];
```

How would I get similar result with these values?

```
first = 1;
second = 1.66;
times = 5;
result = [1, ?, ?, ?, 1.66]
```

Or this

```
first = 1;
second = 1.66;
times = 8;
result = [1, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1.66]
```

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GwrzYL?editors=1010) I have tried if it is of any use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 result = Array.from({ length: times }, (_, i) => first + (second - first) * i / (times - 1));
```

You could create an array containing `times` elements, and then set each slot to a value between `first` and `second`. For that a number between 0 and 1 is generated for all slots  and then the formula does:

```
 // example for 2 times
 first + (second - first) * 0 // = first
 first + (second - first) * 1 // = second
```